# Public address announcements in OITNB

Tags: sound-effects, orange-is-the-new-black

All through the existing 39 episodes of 'Orange is the New Black' you can hear the public address system make announcements.

They are diegetic effects used to create the ambience of a prison, a type of background noise that you would filter out after a while.  We saw this used in MASH, but in that series the announcements were comedic. The announcements are dead pan serious, randomly spaced, and their content does not inform the viewer or advance the plot.  Or do they?

Do the public address announcements have any meaning or relevant connection to the narrative?  Do they 'sneak one in' every so often so as to tease the alert viewer?

**Adding...**
Per commentary asking for samples...

season 3, episode 1 at 14:39, 16:50, 17:14 etc

season 3, episode 2 at 2:56, 9:55, 13:06, etc etc...

Also from the OITNB Wiki...

Man on PA: Available guards...

Man on PA: Inmate Robinson to the visitor area.

Woman on PA: Guard Thompson to the tower.

Man on PA: Inmates, an updates facility rules with inmate discipline list is posted in the day room/

Woman on PA: Armored gates, open number one and two.

Man on PA: Inmate Gonzalez report to the supply room.

(http://orange-is-the-new-black.wikia.com/wiki/I_Wasn%27t_Ready_Transcript)

Cut to the cafeteria, where the daily announcement of "don't forget ladies your usual meals is 1,500 calories.

http://orange-is-the-new-black.wikia.com/wiki/Fear,_and_Other_Smells

Relevant Reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/orangeisthenewblack/comments/1is9u7/catalogue_of_the_announcements_over_the_pa/)

Twitter reference [here](https://twitter.com/oitnb/status/477585484634271744)

---

### Adding...

Comments have asked for samples. These are screen caps of some of the PA announcements in episode 2...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: Please link to specific videos or to actual articles about it... a google search result could be different to every person who views it.